# Animated Menu Stops By Every Element and Delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create a menu with a background sliding horizontally on mouseenter. However when i try to move the mouse from the first one to the fourth one, background stops by on the second and third ones. And the delay is a problem too. Here is my html codes:

```
<div class="menuSecili iconset"></div>
<ul class="iconset fl">
    <li class="secili seciliSg" id="homepage">Homepage</li>
    <li id="corporate">Corporate</li>
    <li id="products">products</li>
    <li id="branches">Branches</li>
    <li id="contact">Contact</li>
</ul>
```

And js:

```
$('ul li').mouseenter(function(){
     $('.menuSecili').animate({'left':$(this).position().left+20},350);
     $('ul li').removeClass('secili');
     $(this).addClass('secili');
});
$('ul').mouseleave(function(){
     $('.menuSecili').animate({'left':$('.seciliSg').position().left+20},350);
     $('ul li').removeClass('secili');
     $('.seciliSg').addClass('secili');            
});
```

JSFiddle link too: http://jsfiddle.net/D2r4E/

Comment: do you mean this, using `stop()`: http://jsfiddle.net/D2r4E/1/  I see you need to add/remove class in animation callback too

Answer (score 0):

It's working now with this code?

```
var site = {
    menuKaydir: function () {
        $('.menuSecili').offset({
            left: $('ul li.secili').offset().left
        });
        $('ul li').mouseenter(function () {
            $('.menuSecili').animate({
                'left': $(this).position().left + 20
            }, 350);
            $('ul li').removeClass('secili');
            $(this).addClass('secili');
        });
        $('ul').mouseleave(function () {
            $('.menuSecili').animate({
                'left': $('.seciliSg').position().left + 20
            }, 350);
            $('ul li').removeClass('secili');
            $('.seciliSg').addClass('secili');
        });
    }
}

$(function () {
    site.menuKaydir();
});
```

Comment: Isn't it the same code as mine? The problem has solved by adding "stop()".